# Move elements in DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

If I have the following structure:

```
<div id="elements">
    <div data-id="5"></div>
    <div data-id="3"></div>
    <div data-id="1"></div>
    <div data-id="4"></div>
    <div data-id="0"></div>
</div>
```

I have no clue how to write function where I can say "Element with data-id = 4 place on position 1". So after I have the result:

```
<div id="elements">
    <div data-id="5"></div>
    <div data-id="4"></div>
    <div data-id="3"></div>
    <div data-id="1"></div>
    <div data-id="0"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do with jQuery?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, unlike other forums, where you can ask for code to be written for you, it's best to ask for help with debugging things here. Please post a [mcve]. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move an element to a specific position, you could use `.eq(index)` to get the element at the desired position, then use `.insertBefore($element)` to place the `<div>` in its place.

```js
var $elements = $('#elements').children(),
    $elementAt1 = $elements.eq(1);

$elements.filter('[data-id=4]').insertBefore($elementAt1);
```

```css
#elements > div:before { content: attr(data-id) }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">
    <div data-id="5"></div>
    <div data-id="3"></div>
    <div data-id="1"></div>
    <div data-id="4"></div>
    <div data-id="0"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To just move `div[data-id="4"]` in position 1

```
$('div[data-id="4"]').insertAfter('div[data-id="5"]');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/nsnod41u/)

any way the pervious code just work if your div with div[data-id="5"] is a first div .. if not use this code

```
$('div[data-id="4"]').insertAfter('#elements > div[data-id]:eq(0)');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/nsnod41u/2/)

Comment: What if `div[data-id="5"]` is not the first child? The only thing that's sure is the one with `[data-id="4"]` needs to be in position `1`.

Comment: @DJDavid98 and that's about assuming if or about code we all seeing in a question??  .. my code work with the posted code in question .. so what is the wrong in that??